# For loop not showing correct count when outputting, showing up number too high in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, count, output

I am having trouble showing up the correct count in my for loop. It works for my previous codes, but when I use this one, the count is too big. What I am trying to do in do to have my for loop count the inputed number and subtract the number each time it runs through. For example:

When I type in 50 using this code:

```
double change; //input variable for change
cin >> change;

//for loop for 50 dollar bills
for (int fif = change; fif >= 50; fif -=50)
{
 b++; //this is the count variable
 change = fif - 50;
} 

if (b == 1)
cout << b << " $50 bill\n";
else
cout <<"";

cout << change; //output the change variable after loop
```

The result will output:

```
1 50 dollar bill
0.00
```

However when I change the numbers to match for $20 bills my code looks like this:

```
  //for loop for twenty dollar bills
 for (int twen = change; twen <= 40 && twen >=20 ; twen -=20)
{
 c++; //count variable
 change = twen - 20;
} 

if (c == 1)
cout << c << " $20 dollar bill\n";
else if (c > 1)
cout << c << " $20 dollar bills\n";
else
cout << "";

cout << change;
```

And the output number always changes for the count for the output. For example if I type in 40:

```
32661 $20 dollar bills
0.00
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you declare `c` as `int c = 0`?

Comment: Hold on, are you initialising b = 0 and c = 0??  I don't see any initialisation for these count variables.  Secondly you haven't specified what your input is for the $20 bill example.

Comment: By the way, please read this: [mcve]. Will help you solve your next problem (s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your counting variable is not initialized. Variables can start existence from 0 by luck (good or bad luck, depending on your attitude). Or they can start from a seemingly random value. In any case, you cannot depend on the initial value of `int` variables.